# Redirect away from login page

Tags: redirect, wp-login-form

I'm trying to find a way to prevent the login screen from showing up when user makes a mistake filling out the login form.

So, right now, I have the login form printed on a custom template. But if the users makes a mistake filling it out, it redirects them to the wordpress form to try again. I want to redirect away from that.

This is the code I had but it's not working.

```
add_action('login_form', 'redirect_invalid_login');

function redirect_invalid_login(){
    global $error;

    if($error)
        header('Location: '.get_bloginfo('url').'/client-login/?message=6');
}
```

Now login_form is too late I believe because stuff already gets printed to the page. I haven't been able to find a hook that works. Is there a hook for this? Or perhaps a different way to do it?

Answer (score 4):

The `login_init` hook is the first one to be called in wp-login.php, so try hooking into it instead.

```
function redirect_invalid_login()
{
    global $error;

    if( $error )
    {
        wp_redirect( get_bloginfo( 'url' ) . '/client-login/?message=6' );
        die();
    }
}
add_action( 'login_init', 'redirect_invalid_login' );
```

If that doesn't work, please provide more details.